# Motorcycle: increasing choke kills engine

Tags: motorcycle, idle

My bike struggles to idle on cold mornings. No issue there: I just open the choke till it warms. However, I must do this ever so slowly and delicately otherwise the engine cuts out. I find this odd as revving the throttle quickly is fine.

Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: Do you mean close the choke and open it as it gets warm?

Answer (score 3):

If you have done any performance mods they may be contributing to your cold idle problem. Exhaust or air intake mods may put you in a borderline lean condition. You could have a lean idle circuit. This could be an adjustment/calibration problem or a dirty carb. When you open the throttle you bypass the idle circuit and the accelerator pump richens the mixture to keep the motor running. If you haven't done any performance  mods I would try some carb cleaner. I have had good luck with "SeaFoam" and PB Blaster "lawnmower tune up in a can". Yes that really is the name of the product. I would try the following.

1.shut off the fuel at the tank.

2.start the motor let it run out of fuel.

3.disconnect the fuel line at the tank

4.spray the carb cleaner into the fuel line, completely fill the hose if you can
 5.reconnect the fuel line to the tank

6.crank the engine just enough to fill the carbs with the cleaner (approx 5 seconds)

7.let the cleaner sit in the carbs for several hours

8.add some cleaner to the fuel tank and turn the fuel shutoff back on

9 start the engine

It may take a few miles for the dirt and sludge to pass thru the carb.